# No EntityManager Bound To Global? Attempting Transaction from onHandlerNotFound

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.3 with Hibernate and am attempting to render my 404 page when a user attempts to access a route that is undefined.

My main template makes a call to the database in order to get a list of items which populates a dropdown in my navbar. This is causing an issue when I attempt to render my 404 template from the Global class inside my onHanderNotFound method, as my 404 template extends my main template.

Is there a work around for this issue? Simply annotating the overridden onHanderNotFound method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional does not correct the issue, either way I get the following Exception:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional**

I've also attempted to call the Controller which has the annotation like so:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(Http.RequestHeader request) {
        return F.Promise.pure(Application.pageNotFound());
    }
}
```

But, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call action inside JPA context, just like actions annoted with `@Transactional` are called:

```java
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(Http.RequestHeader request) {

        return JPA.withTransaction(new F.Function0<F.Promise<Result>>() {
            @Override
            public F.Promise<Result> apply() throws Throwable {
                return F.Promise.pure(Application.pageNotFound());
            }
        });

    }
}
```